# How to moq, two values from the same config, on the same unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have two values i need to test in my unit test using moq, but i can not figure out how to achieve this.. Heres what i have so far. It is working, when getting one of the values, but obviously its overwriting my second call.

```
 [Test(Description = "Test writer only called once")]
        public void Test_Writer_Only_Called_Once()
        {
            //Arrange
            var SendFilesAccessMock = new Mock<ISendFiles>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            var iWriterBci = new Mock<IWriter<BCIData>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var iWriterBji = new Mock<IWriter<BJIData>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var iConfigMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();


           
            **Mock<IConfigurationSection> mockSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
            mockSection.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("\\TestBench\\TestBench2_{0}.bji");

            Mock<IConfiguration> mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            mockConfig.Setup(x => x.GetSection(It.Is<string>(k => k == "AppSettings:bjiFileLocation"))).Returns(mockSection.Object);
            
            mockSection.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("\\TestBench\\TestBench2_{0}.bci");
            mockConfig.Setup(x => x.GetSection(It.Is<string>(k => k == "AppSettings:bciFileLocation"))).Returns(mockSection.Object);**
            ArgumentNullException exceptionThrown = null;
            
            iWriterBji.Setup(obj => obj.Write(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<BJIData>>(), It.IsAny<StreamWriter>()));

           
            //iConfigMock.Setup(c => c.GetSection(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(new Mock<IConfigurationSection>().Object);
           
            var objectToTest = _ = new Api.Business.SendFiles(iWriterBci.Object, iWriterBji.Object,mockConfig.Object);
            //Act
            try
            {
                objectToTest.Write("test", 191);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                exceptionThrown = ex;
            }


            //Assert
            SendFilesAccessMock.VerifyAll();
            iWriterBji.Verify(obj => obj.Write(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<BJIData>>(), It.IsAny<StreamWriter>()), Times.Once());
        }
```

My Calling Code

```
public SendFiles(IWriter<BCIData> bciWriter, IWriter<BJIData> bjiWriter, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _bciWriter = bciWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bciWriter));
            _bjiWriter = bjiWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bjiWriter));
            _configuration = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        }

 public void Write(string benchName, long? orderNumber)
        {
            if(benchName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(benchName));

            if(orderNumber == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderNumber));
            try
            {
                    var benchLocation1 = /*string.Format*/(_configuration.GetValue<string>
                        ("AppSettings:bjiFileLocation")/*, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks*/);
                    var benchLocation2 = _configuration.GetValue<string>
                        ("AppSettings:bciFileLocation");

                    
                var passedOrderNumber = "Get BJI & BCI Data from this number";

                    _bjiDataList = GetBjiData();

                    //D:\TestBench is the location it writes to locally - need to set up folder and share
                    var stream1 = new StreamWriter(benchLocation1);


                    _bjiWriter.Write(_bjiDataList, stream1);
                    stream1.Close();

                    WriteCSVFileAndConfirm(benchLocation2);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I can not seem to figure how i can setup both of the config values i need, as at the moment, both bench are populated with the same config value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate instance of `Mock<IConfigurationSection>` for each configuration section:

```cs
Mock<IConfigurationSection> mockSection1 = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
mockSection.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("\\TestBench\\TestBench2_{0}.bji");

Mock<IConfiguration> mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
mockConfig
    .Setup(x => x.GetSection(It.Is<string>(k => k == "AppSettings:bjiFileLocation")))
.Returns(mockSection1.Object);

Mock<IConfigurationSection> mockSection2 = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
mockSection2.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("\\TestBench\\TestBench2_{0}.bci");
mockConfig
    .Setup(x => x.GetSection(It.Is<string>(k => k == "AppSettings:bciFileLocation")))
    .Returns(mockSection2.Object);
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you very much.